# Error 121 can't create table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a database created in mySql workbench into phpMyAdmin (WAMP server) , when I try to import it I get error :

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table '.\mydb\team.frm' (errno: 121)
```

Below is the executed SQL script

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 03/03/15 13:06:58
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Team`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Team` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`TeamName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`GoverningBody` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Competitor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Competitor` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Age` INT NOT NULL,
`Nationality` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `Title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `ContactNumber` INT NOT NULL,
 `team_id` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `TeamID_idx` (`team_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `TeamID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`Team` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Card`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Card` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`IssueDate` DATE NOT NULL,
`ExpiryDate` DATE NOT NULL,
`Status` ENUM('Active','Expired','Lost') NOT NULL,
`competitor_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `CompetitorID_idx` (`competitor_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `CompetitorID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`competitor_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`Competitor` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Venue`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Venue` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
 `referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Stadium` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Fixture`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Fixture` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Time` TIME NOT NULL,
`Date` DATE NOT NULL,
`Type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`venue_id` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `VenueID_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `VenueID`
FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Venue` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Authorisation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Authorisation` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`fixture_id` INT NOT NULL,
`card_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `FixtureID_idx` (`fixture_id` ASC),
INDEX `CardID_idx` (`card_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `FixtureID`
FOREIGN KEY (`fixture_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Fixture` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `CardID`
FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Card` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


 -- -----------------------------------------------------
 -- Table `mydb`.`Log`
 -- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Log` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `card_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `venue_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `LogTime` TIME NOT NULL,
 `LogDate` DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `CardID_idx` (`card_id` ASC),
 INDEX `VenueID_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `CardID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`Card` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `VenueID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`Venue` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: change `team_id DATETIME NOT NULL,` to `team_id INT NOT NULL,`

Comment: Done it and unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: There are several other errors like using the same index name or constraint name in other tables which are already defined in former tables. **Example** `CardID_idx` in `Authorisation` and `Log` tables. Check others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the changes in the comments above worked for me (the `DATETIME` to `INT` and making unique constraint and index names).  As a safe practice, in our organization we always name our indexes/constraints as `(table1Identifier)_(table2Identifier)_(constraintType)`...so something like `Log_Card_idx` or `Auth_Fixture_FK`.  Just a thought.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 03/03/15 13:06:58
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Team`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Team` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`TeamName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`GoverningBody` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Competitor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Competitor` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Age` INT NOT NULL,
`Nationality` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `Title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `ContactNumber` INT NOT NULL,
 `team_id` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `TeamID_idx` (`team_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `TeamID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`Team` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Card`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Card` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`IssueDate` DATE NOT NULL,
`ExpiryDate` DATE NOT NULL,
`Status` ENUM('Active','Expired','Lost') NOT NULL,
`competitor_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `CompetitorID_idx` (`competitor_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `CompetitorID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`competitor_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`Competitor` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Venue`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Venue` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
 `referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Stadium` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Fixture`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Fixture` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Time` TIME NOT NULL,
`Date` DATE NOT NULL,
`Type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`venue_id` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `VenueID_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `VenueID`
FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Venue` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Authorisation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Authorisation` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`fixture_id` INT NOT NULL,
`card_id` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `Auth_FixtureID_idx` (`fixture_id` ASC),
INDEX `Auth_CardID_idx` (`card_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `Auth_FixtureID`
FOREIGN KEY (`fixture_id`)
REFERENCES `Fixture` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `Auth_CardID`
FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`)
REFERENCES `Card` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


 -- -----------------------------------------------------
 -- Table `mydb`.`Log`
 -- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Log` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `referred_as` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `card_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `venue_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `LogTime` TIME NOT NULL,
 `LogDate` DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `Log_CardID_idx` (`card_id` ASC),
 INDEX `Log_VenueID_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `Log_CardID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`Card` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `Log_VenueID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
 REFERENCES `Venue` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```